# Converting .PFX to .PEM programmatically?

Tags: certificate, pem, pfx

I need to programmatically extract certificates and their private keys from a MS certificate store, and get them to the .PEM format somehow.  I don't want to use OpenSSL at the command line, as I would like to keep everything in memory, avoiding files.

I can export them from Windows to a PFX-format blob using PFXExportCertStoreEx().  I tested that by writing it to a file and converting it to .PEM with OpenSSL.  The resulting .PEM file works fine.  So the remaining problem is to get them to the .PEM format in memory.

We've integrated a different SSL library that wants .PEM.  (It's not OpenSSL...)  So I'd like to accomplish this without also including OpenSSL source into our C++ project.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell us the SSL library you are working with?

Comment: It's yaSSL, which seems to want .PEM files.

Answer (score 1):

How about statically linking to OpenSSL .lib files?

I have adapted some examples using OpenSSL to do this, you can find c++ code to convert pfx to pem here:
https://pubrepos.motes.camp/browse/libCurlVB.NET-native.git/

And this file contains VB.NET Interop code to convert PFX to PEM using OpenSSL:

https://pubrepos.motes.camp/browse/libCurlVB.NET-native.git/blob/HEAD/LibCurlDecl.vb